# How to individually render just the chosen class in a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I'm working on some practice code where a list of customer accounts and cards is to be displayed (see the attached image).

[image: click_to_expand]

Each of the "Accounts" contains multiple "Cards", and I want this program to show the cards that the designated Account contains. For example, if I click the button "Account 1", only the cards that are stored in Account 1 should be displayed.

However, when I click any of the Account buttons, all of the cards are displayed (see the attached image)

[image: all_cards_displayed]

I meant to design the v-for loop to display just the chosen account's cards by setting a boolean variable and letting the card information be displayed only when the boolean value is true, but as you can see from the output screenshot, this is apparently not working.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I get this program behave the way I described?

Here is my code.

(v-for loop part)

```
 <!-- If there is data for accounts, print it all out and then show the separate ID the user clicks on -->
            <div class="account-card-list"  v-for="(account,index) in accountsData" :key="account.id">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span class="account" @click="clickAccountBtn(account.id)"  v-if="account.accountId == account.accountId"> 
                          Account {{index+1}}: 
                        </span>    
                        <span v-if="!accountBtnExpanded"> &nbsp; (← Click to expand)</span>
                        <span v-else> &nbsp; (← Click to fold)</span>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <ul v-if="accountBtnExpanded">
                            <li class="myList" v-for="(card,index) in cardsData" :key="card.id">
                                <span class="card" @click="getCardInfo(card.id)" v-if="card.accountId == account.id ">  
                                  <span class="cardBtn" @click="clickCardBtn()">Card {{index+1}} </span> &nbsp; &nbsp;  {{ card }}    
                                  <span v-if="cardBtnChosen">
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="cardInfo">CARDINFO:</span> {{ cardData }}
                                  </span> 
                                </span>                         
                            </li>
                            <ul>
                                <br>
                                <li ></li>
                            </ul>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

and this is how the `clickAccountBtn(account.id)` method works.

```
methods: {
      clickAccountBtn(accountId){
        if(this.accountBtnExpanded == false){
          this.accountBtnExpanded = true;
          this.findAccount(accountId);
        } else {
          this.accountBtnExpanded = false; 
        }
      },
```

Comment: you'll need to access others card to set their `accountBtnExpended` to false OR you can also save the last expended card in a global variable and set only the `accountBtnExpended` of this one to false

Comment: Do you mean that I should save the index of the last expanded card information as a global variable and only display the designated index's card information?

Comment: You can use the `index` from your v-for loop, and pass it into your function. Then, find that card index programmatically to expand only that card. Your issue is that your boolean is bound to every single card, so expanding one of them will expand all of them.

Comment: Should I prepare multiple boolean variables, like an array of boolean?  For example, if there are 10 cards, should I have variables like "isExpanded[10]"? (of course the size of the array should be dynamically allocated in that case)

Comment: IMO the best way would be to create a "card" component and use this one in the loop, it would actually bind each card to a bool

Comment: Actually there is already a Card component (though I didn't show it because it gets too long if I show every single part of the code), and that Card component is basically used to interact with the card information in the database via API. This Card component has methods like getCardInfo(id), getCards(), updateCardAddress(), createNewCard(), all of which involve some kind of interaction with API using axios. Should I create another component to be used in this particular v-for loop?

Comment: Feels very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922053/repeated-elements-have-the-same-expand-variable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to hold your selected accounts.

In data

```
selectedIds:[]
```

In template

```
<ul v-if="selectedIds.includes(account.id)">
```

Then, in your click handler, toggle the item id in the array.

```
clickAccountBtn(accountId) {
  const idx = this.selectedIds.indexOf(accountId);
  if (idx > -1) {
    this.selectedIds.splice(idx, 1);
  }
  else {
    this.selectedIds.push(accountId);
  }
```

You could also use an `object` or `set`, or even restrict only a single id, but the general approach will still be the same.

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for! When I tried it myself I realized that the selectedIds doesn't have to be an array. It was fine with just a primitive type variable selectedId, and then just assign the value like this.selectedId = accountId. Then set the condition of v-if statement as <ul v-if="accountBtnExpanded && selectedId == account.id"> . But anyway your answer was a great hint for me, and I appreciate that :D

Comment: I updated the comment at end to include your single selection use case.