# Vue: Best way to handle state when having a dynamic number of items?

Tags: vue.js

If I need state to control parts of an element, how would I do that when I have a potentially infinite amount items in a loop.
I just have pseudocode here to get my question across.  I want `disableText` state to disable the input for the button but not other buttons in the loop.  What is the best way to handle that ?  Would I incorporate the key or index into it to make it unique?

```
<div v-for="item in items">
   <input @change="submitText(item)" :disabled="this.disableText" />
</div>

///
submitText: function(e) {
     //do something
     this.disableText = true; 
}
```

Comment: Does the answer I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922053/repeated-elements-have-the-same-expand-variable) help at all? It was called `show` rather than `disableText` in that question but the core idea seems the same.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, thanks!